# How to make VS Unit Test show the Error Message from exceptions other than UnitTestAssertException?

Tags: unit-testing, exception, moq, assert, vs-unit-testing-framework

I'm using [VS Unit Testing Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Unit_Testing_Framework) and [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/).

When a Moq verification fails, I'll get a Moq.MockException. In the Test Results window, instead of showing the helpful message inside the exception, it just says "Test method XXX threw exception: ..."

Is there a way to tell the VS Unit Test framework always display the message of exceptions of a given type (like Moq.MockException)?

Comment: Arggh!  I just wanted to say I feel your pain...

Comment: I decided to move away from MSTest. I'm using xUnit and TestDriven.NET now. I tried Gallio, but  it didn't work with my VS2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: No. You have to open the *Test Details* window for that in MSTest (btw. that's one of many reasons why I think MSTest is not the best choice for doing Test-driven development...).

Anyway, there are two possible ways to achieve this (at least that I know of):

1. Use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) to run your tests.
2. Use the free [Gallio](http://www.gallio.org) automation platform to run your tests.

HTH!
Thomas

Comment: I'm indeed considering to move to another unit test framework. Which one is your choice?

Comment: If you consider it, I would recommend Gallio. It is basically an automation platform that can run all kinds of testing frameworks (e.g. NUnit, xUnit.net, MSTest...) and comes bundled with MbUnit, which is the most feature-rich and flexible testing framework anyway. You most likely won't need anything else...